# Need some help understanding an argument as a function

Tags: python

```
def question6(f,x,y,z):
    fx=f(x)
    fy=f(y)
    fz=f(z)
    if fx==fy :
       if fy==fz :
          print("Applying f to all three values gives the same result")
          return 1
       else :
          print("Applying f to x and y gives the same result")
          return 2
    elif fx==fz :
       print("Applying f to x and z gives the same result")
       return 3
    elif fy==fz :
       print("Applying f to y and z gives the same result")
       return 4 
    else :
       print("Applying f to each of the three values gives a
              different result")
       return 5
```

Theres this piece of code ive been shown where the argument f is passed as function.
In the code f = f(x), but how does this work is f(x) doesn't mean anything or do anything

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, please paste the real code here.

Comment: Indentation has been fixed

Comment: @HassanMiah you can check whether the function is callable or not, meaning whether the function does something or not .Check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/callable-in-python/)

Comment: Try and see how it fails.

Answer (score 0):

`f(x)` means "call the function `f` with `x` as an argument".  If `f` is a function that doesn't do anything, then `f(x)` won't do anything.  If `f` is a function that does something, then `f(x)` will do that thing to `x`.

Here's an example where it would actually do something:

```
from typing import Callable

def do_four_times(f: Callable[[int], None]) -> None:
    for x in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        f(x)

def print_double(i: int) -> None:
    print(i * 2)

do_four_times(print_double)
print("Who do we appreciate?")
```